# why I get error-runtime with this python youtubedownloader code

Tags: python, error-handling, runtime-error

How can I download video from YouTube is there some MWE??
I want to download a playlist from YouTube site:
(I want to download a video from YouTube as follows)
`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_oHTzIsLMGc`

With this code

```
from pytube import YouTube

#ask for the link from user
link = input("Enter the link of YouTube video you want to download:  ")
yt = YouTube(link)

#Showing details
print("Title: ",yt.title)
print("Number of views: ",yt.views)
print("Length of video: ",yt.length)
print("Rating of video: ",yt.rating)
#Getting the highest resolution possible
ys = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()

#Starting download
print("Downloading...")
ys.download()
print("Download completed!!")
```

I'm getting this
**ERROR**

```
$ python dl.py
Enter the link of YouTube video you want to download:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_oHTzIsLMGc
Title:  CAER EN EL SUEÑO PROFUNDO,Sanación del Estrés,Ansiedad y Estados Depresivos,Restauración Corporal#16
Number of views:  34789
Length of video:  367200
Rating of video:  None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytube/__main__.py", line 181, in fmt_streams
    extract.apply_signature(stream_manifest, self.vid_info, self.js)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytube/extract.py", line 409, in apply_signature
    cipher = Cipher(js=js)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytube/cipher.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.throttling_plan = get_throttling_plan(js)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytube/cipher.py", line 405, in get_throttling_plan
    raw_code = get_throttling_function_code(js)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytube/cipher.py", line 311, in get_throttling_function_code
    name = re.escape(get_throttling_function_name(js))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytube/cipher.py", line 296, in get_throttling_function_name
    raise RegexMatchError(
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: get_throttling_function_name: could not find match for multiple

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/hynek0/Desktop/FU/VILLA/dl.py", line 13, in <module>
    ys = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytube/__main__.py", line 296, in streams
    return StreamQuery(self.fmt_streams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytube/__main__.py", line 188, in fmt_streams
    extract.apply_signature(stream_manifest, self.vid_info, self.js)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytube/extract.py", line 409, in apply_signature
    cipher = Cipher(js=js)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytube/cipher.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.throttling_plan = get_throttling_plan(js)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytube/cipher.py", line 405, in get_throttling_plan
    raw_code = get_throttling_function_code(js)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytube/cipher.py", line 311, in get_throttling_function_code
    name = re.escape(get_throttling_function_name(js))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytube/cipher.py", line 296, in get_throttling_function_name
    raise RegexMatchError(
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: get_throttling_function_name: could not find match for multiple
```

**EDIT line 264**

```
$ pytube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_oHTzIsLMGc
Loading video...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pytube", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytube/cli.py", line 53, in main
    _perform_args_on_youtube(youtube, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytube/cli.py", line 60, in _perform_args_on_youtube
    download_highest_resolution_progressive(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytube/cli.py", line 479, in download_highest_resolution_progressive
    _download(stream, target=target)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytube/cli.py", line 256, in _download
    filesize_megabytes = stream.filesize // 1048576
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytube/streams.py", line 157, in filesize
    self._filesize = request.filesize(self.url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytube/request.py", line 204, in filesize
    return int(head(url)["content-length"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytube/request.py", line 268, in head
    response_headers = _execute_request(url, method="HEAD").info()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytube/request.py", line 37, in _execute_request
    return urlopen(request, timeout=timeout)  # nosec
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 561, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my code to download a video or a playlist:

```
from pytube import YouTube, Playlist

# Function to download a single video
def download_video(url):
    try:
        yt = YouTube(url)
        stream = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
        print(f"Downloading video: {yt.title}")
        stream.download()
        print("Download completed!")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {str(e)}")

# Function to download a playlist
def download_playlist(url):
    try:
        playlist = Playlist(url)
        print(f"Total videos in playlist: {len(playlist.video_urls)}")
        for video_url in playlist.video_urls:
            download_video(video_url)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {str(e)}")

# Main program
user_input = input("Enter YouTube video URL or playlist URL: ")
if "youtube.com/playlist" in user_input:
    download_playlist(user_input)
else:
    download_video(user_input)
```

output:

```
PS D:\pgm\python\pratice> & C:/Python/Python_3.11.3/python.exe d:/pgm/python/pratice/test2.py
Enter YouTube video URL or playlist URL: https://youtu.be/WuAAWQshbTM
Downloading video: How to Do 15 PULLUPS OR MORE in a Row (GUARANTEED!)
Download completed!
PS D:\pgm\python\pratice> & C:/Python/Python_3.11.3/python.exe d:/pgm/python/pratice/test2.py
Enter YouTube video URL or playlist URL: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjqueTFOWIlKOKqeRMB7K-64iGresYwCn
Total videos in playlist: 2
Downloading video: 30 Minute Full Body Dumbbell HIIT Workout [ADVANCED]
Download completed!
Downloading video: Ultimate Full-Body Dumbbell Workout | Andy Speer
Download completed!
```

Comment: This doesn't work well: `$ python a2.py
Enter YouTube video URL or playlist URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_oHTzIsLMGc
Error: get_throttling_function_name: could not find match for multiple
`

Comment: Oh now it works, I just inserted a new URL: `https://youtu.be/WuAAWQshbTM`. What is this stuff ?? How can I match `youtu.be/W` with `youtube.com/watch?v=W` ?? I.e. how can I find the corresponding `youtu.be` to `youtube.com/watch?` ?? WIth this **youtu.be** works everything just fine, what is that ?

Comment: **BUT** when it comes to **lists** I'm still getting an error: `Enter the link of
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytube/a3.py", line 6, in <module>
    yt = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGIOVY7XCUF6jDx8a2Y2innXZQXg8qPZu')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytube/__main__.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.video_id = extract.video_id(ur
    raise RegexMatchError(caller="regex_search", pattern=pattern)
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: regex_search: could not find match for (?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a BUG in `pytube`. A issue has already raised [RegexMatchError: get_throttling_function_name: could not find match for multiple #1707](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1707)) in the repository. See this [comment](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1707#issuecomment-1616464219) for a workaround soultion.

Comment: Right, but they say `fix the problem by removing the ; from the pattern in line 287 of pytube.cipher` and I cannot find `pytube.cipher`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. go to the pytube library (you find the location using `pip show pytube` )
   [image]
2. change cipher.py -> get_throttling_function_name -> function_patterns to

```
function_patterns = [
    # https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/29326#issuecomment-865985377
    # https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/commit/48416bc4a8f1d5ff07d5977659cb8ece7640dcd8
    # var Bpa = [iha];
    # ...
    # a.C && (b = a.get("n")) && (b = Bpa[0](b), a.set("n", b),
    # Bpa.length || iha("")) }};
    # In the above case, `iha` is the relevant function name
    r'a\.[a-zA-Z]\s*&&\s*\([a-z]\s*=\s*a\.get\("n"\)\)\s*&&.*?\|\|\s*([a-z]+)',
    r'\([a-z]\s*=\s*([a-zA-Z0-9$]+)(\[\d+\])?\([a-z]\)', ]
```

in my case it is 264 line
[image]
4. run the py script
this worked for me

Comment: It still gives an error though a different one: see **EDIT line 264** in my OQ.